# What are basemaps?

Tags: qgis

I am really struggling to understand QGIS.
Is a basemap something I construct or is this something I just add e.g, a package in RStudio?

Comment: I would say it's just a finished map to use as background. For example execute this in the python console and get google maps, google satellite, esri maps and more as XYZ tiles: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/klakar/QGIS_resources/master/collections/Geosupportsystem/python/qgis_basemaps.py

Comment: Addendum to @BERA's comment: A basemap is not something that you can easily construct and it's not a package.

Comment: A basemap is just a background map layer (or set of layers). You can create it yourself, you can download packaged basemaps (e.g. [natural earth](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/)), or you can add prebuilt basemap web services (e.g [quickmapservices](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/))